# Left side menu pad - make one side part blurred and transparent

Tags: html, css, transparent, blur

You can find picture in post. I implemented side menu, and when `hover` on menu items, another menu pops up near it, with options (in this example, literally it is menu with header styles). As you can see, on right side, it is a little bit transparent and blurred, how can I achieve this effect? Also, it has scrollbar visible always, but my scrollbar disappears. How can I implement these two design features?

[image: Click to see image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: there is css property `filter: blur(10px);` on the background =, combined with opacity will give you the result. Just keep in mind that blur effect is very expensive for browser to render - which can cost you longer time to render of the page

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your image in this jfiddle

css filter property will blur the entire element, so every child element will be blurred as well

```
filter: blur(5px);
```

use instead:

```
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6npd0v4k/5/

Just use the style of your scrollbar but it should render correctly